# XML parsing using C#, get specific value

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<XML>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="ActionLogPrompt">2</Property>
    <Property name="Answer"></Property>
    <Property name="SubQBackColour">#FF0000</Property>
  </Properties>
</XML>
```

What I am trying to do is to find SubQBackColour and get the value of "#FF0000". I am trying to do that with the code below, but I cannot figure out what to call to get the name of the property and check for this SubQBackColour.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    node = reader.NodeType;

    if (node == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        if (reader.Name.Equals("XML"))
        {
            reader.Read();

            if (reader.Name.Equals("Properties"))
            {
                reader.Read();

                if (reader.Name.Equals("Property"))
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    node = reader.NodeType;

                    if ((node == XmlNodeType.Text))
                    {
                         string thingy = reader.GetAttribute("name");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the XML?

Comment: <XML><Properties><Property name="ActionLogPrompt">2</Property><Property name="Answer"></Property><Property name="SubQBackColour">#FF0000</Property></Properties></XML>

Comment: for some kind of reason does that weird thing out of my xml lines

Comment: deserialize the xml to strongly typed c# object.

Comment: Do you *really* need to use XmlReader? This would be a one-liner in LINQ to XML...

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: No need to go that far... LINQ to XML makes it simple without adding any extra types

Comment: Try to use SelectSingleNode() together with XPath. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode(v=vs.110).aspx . This will make your code more readable.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will try now the LINQ to XML, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
 string sXML = "<XML>"+
                        "<Properties>"+
                            "<Property name=\"ActionLogPrompt\">2</Property>"+
                            "<Property name=\"Answer\"></Property>"+
                            "<Property name=\"SubQBackColour\">#FF0000</Property>"+
                        "</Properties></XML>";

        XDocument doc3 = XDocument.Parse(sXML);
        var v= from p in doc3.Descendants("Property")
                       where p.Value == "#FF0000"
                           select p.Attribute("name").Value;

        Console.WriteLine(v);
```

You will get value of "name" attribute as "SubQBackColour". You can change the query to get whatever you want.

The best implementation would be to create a class to hold property name and value and get that as output.

Something like

```
 public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

 string sXML = "<XML>"+
                        "<Properties>"+
                            "<Property name=\"ActionLogPrompt\">2</Property>"+
                            "<Property name=\"Answer\"></Property>"+
                            "<Property name=\"SubQBackColour\">#FF0000</Property>"+
                        "</Properties></XML>";

        XDocument doc3 = XDocument.Parse(sXML);
        var v4 = from p in doc3.Descendants("Property")
                 where p.Value == "#FF0000"
                 select new Property
                 {
                     Name = p.Attribute("name").Value,
                     Value = p.Value
                 };

        Console.WriteLine(v4.FirstOrDefault().Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("c:\\yourxml.xml");
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Properties");
string actionLogPrompt= "", answer= "", subQBackColour="";
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
actionLogPrompt = node.SelectSingleNode("ActionLogPrompt").InnerText;
answer = node.SelectSingleNode("Answer").InnerText;
subQBackColour= node.SelectSingleNode("SubQBackColour").InnerText;
MessageBox.Show(actionLogPrompt+ " " + answer+ " " + subQBackColour);
}
```

Comment: This gives me the following Error : foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'XmlNodeList' because 'XmlNodeList' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' . I have tried to google for a fix but cannot really figure out how to do it.

Comment: I would avoid using the `XmlDocument` API these days if you can possibly avoid it. LINQ to XML is considerably cleaner.